# lodash _.uniqWith performance hit

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am having a real big performance hit with `_.uniqWith(newSelectedModelList, _.isEqual);`.

I am comparing a array with 2100 elements. Each element has `{ name: 'foo', year: '1993'}`, `{ name: 'foo', year: '1993'}`, `{ name: 'foo', year: '2000'}` and removing the duplicates that have the same `name` and `year`.

Is there a faster way to do this? Or a better tool than lodash?

Comment: What is "performance hit" being compared to?

Comment: Is the array data coming from a database / server at all? It's probably much faster to remove duplicates server-side.

Comment: Try https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#uniqBy using `function(obj) {return obj.name + ',' + obj.year}` as criterion. This will be `O(n)`

Comment: even with the `function(foo) {console.log(foo)}` as criterion it is super slow. With a simple for loop and console.log, much faster.

Comment: "it is super slow" on 2k elements? Like how long does it take?

Comment: What do you mean by _"and removing the duplicates"_? Are you trying to remove elements from original array, or return new array which does not contain duplicate elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use ES6 `filter` and `Set`. The following function passes a `Set` as the context (`this`) for the callback:

```js
function uniques(arr) { 
    return arr.filter(function ({year, name}, key) { 
        return !this.has(key = year + name) && this.add(key);
    }, new Set());
}
// Sample data
var newSelectedModelList = [
    { name: 'foo', year: '1993'}, 
    { name: 'foo', year: '1993'}, 
    { name: 'foo', year: '2000'}
];
// Output result
console.log(uniques(newSelectedModelList));
```

In case you want the filtering to happen in the given variable, and not in a new array returned by the function, I suggest to just empty the given array and repopulate it: it will be faster for longer arrays than to splice the duplicates out, one-by-one:

```js
function uniques(arr) { 
    var res = arr.filter(function ({year, name}, key) { 
        return !this.has(key = year + name) && this.add(key);
    }, new Set());
    // replace content in arr:
    arr.splice(0, arr.length, res);
}
// Sample data
var newSelectedModelList = [
    { name: 'foo', year: '1993'}, 
    { name: 'foo', year: '1993'}, 
    { name: 'foo', year: '2000'}
];
// replace in-place:
uniques(newSelectedModelList);
// Output result
console.log(newSelectedModelList);
```

On [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y5xc3qwb/3/) I posted a performance comparison with the solution that [guest271314 had posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40536166/5459839) at the time I write this. On my PC the console output reports these measurements:

```
number of original elements:  30000
   solution count duration
----------- ----- --------
    trincot 14456 00020.14
guest271314 14456 00351.99
```

The count column gives the number of unique elements retained in the final result. This number can change in different runs, as the input array is a bit of random. The last column gives the time used in milliseconds.

Comment: Interestingly `console.time()`, `console.timeEnd()` logs `0.1n`, then `1.2n` every several calls?

Comment: @guest271314, you may need to repeat the test with a larger data set. Do you have a fiddle with your test?

Comment: Did not try with jsfiddle. Used stacksnippets, which may be the issue. Note also, Question includes text _"and removing the duplicates"_, where `.filter()` returns a new array, does not remove duplicates from original array.

Comment: True, I am aware of that, but I believe building a new array and assigning it to the original variable might give a performance improvement.